# Producing a Java program for other systems

Tags: java, excel

I've been working on a Java program for a company over the summer and it is nearing completion. Being something of a novice programmer, I've never produced a program for use on other systems using files I've created. My program reads and writes to Excel using Apache Poi, and currently the Excel file being used lies in a specific directory specified by the program. The program also uses some images that lie in directories specified by the code.

How could I make this program runnable on other systems? Would it be possible to have the program create an Excel document whenever it is "installed" on another system?

Currently I'm using Eclipse and the systems are windows 7.

Comment: Why does it need to create an Excel document when it's installed? If you want it to work properly on other systems, don't hardcode paths. Make them configurable or let the user choose it at the time of generation.

Comment: As I said I'm a novice at Java, I'm asking how I can make it work on other systems.

Comment: Try running it on another system, and solve each problem as it comes up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Comment: You have to use OpenFile- and SaveFile-Dialogs where the user can choose folder and filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pack your application in a .jar, actually a zip file with inside .class files and *resource* files. Those resource files, like your images, can be taken with `getClass().getResource("path/x.png")` or `getResourceAsStream`. The path is either package relative or absolute: "/abc/def.jpg".

These resources must be read-only (as they are inside the .jar). However you may store an Excel *template* as resource, and copy that to the user's directory.

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

Will give the user's directory where you may copy your resource to.

```
Path appWorkspace = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "myapp");
Files.createDirectories(appWorkspace);
Path xlsx = appWorkspace.resolve("untitled.xlsx");
Files.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/empty.xlsx"),
    xlsx);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like what I'm looking for, though my only concern is the Excel file being overwritten, though I think I can get around that by just checking whether the file exists or not.

Comment: `Files.copy` (and other functions) has a vararg argument with `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` and such.

Comment: Tried testing this code but I'm getting a null pointer exception on the path xlsx line, should there be a folder called data inside my project? Also, untitled.xlsx doesn't seem to be appearing in myapp.

Comment: NullPointerException happens when the resource file cannot be found on the class path. The path is free, but is typically under src, for maven builds in src/main/resources. If you produce a .jar then open it in 7zip or such and look for the path and file you wanted.